# SQL Server stored procedure - Insert good records and capture error records while doing Insert select

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to insert to a table by selecting from my staging table, due to some 'not null' type columns and data types some records throws error.

How to insert the the non-error records and capture the error records in another table?

The thing is I don't want to stop my insert as it has millions of good records. Also, I could not predict which column will throw error.

I tried to play with TRY CATCH, but not helping. I can get the error but no good record is inserted.

Sample code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Procedure1  
    @FileName varchar(240), 
    @Status varchar(50), 
    @Count int, 
    @Date datetime

    DECLARE @FileId AS BIGINT, @linkId AS BIGINT
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN
        INSERT INTO finalTable (Date, billno, vendor, vendorId, repName, location)
            SELECT 
                Date, billno, vendor, vendorId, 
                CONCAT(repFirstName + repLastName),
                CAST(NULLIF(Location, '') AS int) Location

        INSERT INTO summaryTable (Date, billno, vendor)
            SELECT Date, billno, vendor 
            FROM finalTable 
            WHERE id > SELECT MAX(id) FROM finalTable

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

**Expected result**: out of 157828 - 157825 records inserted, 3 records to be pushed to an error table with similar structure of main table with all columns as type `nvarchar` and accepts any type of record.

Comment: Please, share your TRY CATCH code that did not work.

Comment: BEGIN
 BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRAN
 Query1 here....
 Query2 here....
  COMMIT TRAN
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
  SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(),ERROR_SEVERITY(),ERROR_STATE(),ERROR_PROCEDURE(),ERROR_LINE(),ERROR_MESSAGE();
 END CATCH
END
Result is : Cannot insert the value NULL into column '-----', table '--------------'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: The input parameter column types match the tables, no?  If it won't insert into the table why is it accepted by your proceedure?

Comment: This is data warehouse type action so maybe you could have a look at SSIS [redirecting errors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykBKmOiYl-I)

Comment: @SteveC Actual source is loaded into a table that has all fields as nvarchar and accepts any data. In step1 I'm moving data from stage table to an organised actual table with proper data types. In this process I don't wan to stop loading all data as only few records having error, so I accept all in procedure and want to capture error records in a error table.

Comment: @Vasanth, SSIS is set up to do what you're attepting to do.  There's a Data Conversion Error object and you could do whatever you wish with the errors.  The answer from Christoph would work and leave you with 3 files, the nvarchar (with everything), final, and error.  If you just wanted final and error, you could insert into a view and create an INSTEAD OF trigger on the view.  Then run the 2 inserts

Comment: @SteveC I could not use SSIS and I'm not clear how to update 'IsValid' column in Christoph answer. Second part to trigger is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a step-by-step explanation of what I mean based on some column names you provide in your example. As I didn't have your table definition, I assumed something and you have to adapt it to your needs.

Create the `StagingTable`. I chose to work with GUIDs to be able to use the same IDs for all of the 3 tables (`StagingTable_Id = FinalTable_Id = ErrorTable_Id`). When working with GUIDs make sure not to take it as the physical sort order of the records in the table (clustered key). I choose the point-in-time when the record was stored in the `StagingTable` instead for all 3 tables).

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.StagingTable(
    StagingTable_Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
    StagingTable_ImportDateUtc DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL,
    StagingTable_DateTime NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    StagingTable_BillNo NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    StagingTable_VendorId NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    StagingTable_RepFirstName NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    StagingTable_RepLastName NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    StagingTable_LocationId NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_StagingTable PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (StagingTable_Id ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
ALTER TABLE dbo.StagingTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_StagingTable_StagingTable_ID DEFAULT (NEWID()) FOR StagingTable_Id;
ALTER TABLE dbo.StagingTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_StagingTable_StagingTable_ImportDateUtc DEFAULT (SYSUTCDATETIME()) FOR StagingTable_ImportDateUtc;
ALTER TABLE dbo.StagingTable SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = DISABLE);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_StagingTable01 ON dbo.StagingTable (StagingTable_ImportDateUtc ASC) ON [PRIMARY];
```

The error table has the same structure as the StagingTable:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ErrorTable(
    ErrorTable_Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
    ErrorTable_ImportDateUtc DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL,
    ErrorTable_DateTime NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    ErrorTable_BillNo NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    ErrorTable_VendorId NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    ErrorTable_RepFirstName NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    ErrorTable_RepLastName NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    ErrorTable_LocationId NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ErrorTable PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (ErrorTable_Id ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
ALTER TABLE dbo.ErrorTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_ErrorTable_ErrorTable_ID DEFAULT (NEWID()) FOR ErrorTable_Id;
ALTER TABLE dbo.ErrorTable SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = DISABLE);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_ErrorTable01 ON dbo.ErrorTable (ErrorTable_ImportDateUtc ASC) ON [PRIMARY];
```

But the final table has already the structure of the converted data types:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FinalTable(
    FinalTable_Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
    FinalTable_ImportDateUtc DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL,
    FinalTable_DateTime DATETIME2(7) NOT NULL,
    FinalTable_BillNo INT NOT NULL,
    FinalTable_VendorId INT NOT NULL,
    FinalTable_RepName NVARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    FinalTable_LocationId INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_FinalTable PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (FinalTable_Id ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
ALTER TABLE dbo.FinalTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_FinalTable_FinalTable_Id DEFAULT (NEWID()) FOR FinalTable_Id;
ALTER TABLE dbo.FinalTable SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = DISABLE);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_FinalTable01 ON dbo.FinalTable (FinalTable_ImportDateUtc ASC) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Next we create the conversion view, which serves 2 purposes:

- It filters the view to contain only the records that have not yet been processed (whose id is neither in the `FinalTable` not the `ErrorTable`).
- It tries to convert each field of the `StagingTable`-records into their target format. For the fields where the conversion fails, it assigns `NULL`.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.V_StagingConversion
AS
SELECT 
    st.StagingTable_Id, 
    st.StagingTable_ImportDateUtc, 
    st.StagingTable_DateTime, 
    TRY_CONVERT(datetime2, st.StagingTable_DateTime, 121) AS FinalTable_DateTime,
    st.StagingTable_BillNo,
    TRY_CAST(st.StagingTable_BillNo AS INT) AS FinalTable_BillNo,
    st.StagingTable_VendorId,
    TRY_CAST(st.StagingTable_VendorId AS INT) AS FinalTable_VendorId,
    st.StagingTable_RepFirstName, 
    st.StagingTable_RepLastName,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(st.StagingTable_RepFirstName, '') + N' ' + ISNULL(st.StagingTable_RepLastName, ''))) AS FinalTable_RepName, 
    st.StagingTable_LocationId,
    TRY_CAST(st.StagingTable_LocationId AS INT) AS FinalTable_LocationId
FROM StagingTable st
LEFT OUTER JOIN FinalTable ft ON st.StagingTable_Id = ft.FinalTable_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ErrorTable et ON st.StagingTable_Id = et.ErrorTable_Id
WHERE (ft.FinalTable_Id IS NULL) AND (et.ErrorTable_Id IS NULL);
```

Then we create a view that is based on the previous one and that decides whether the record is valid or not:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.V_StagingValidation
AS
SELECT 
    *, 
    CAST(CASE WHEN FinalTable_DateTime IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 
            CASE WHEN FinalTable_BillNo IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 
                CASE WHEN FinalTable_VendorId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 
                    CASE WHEN (LEN(FinalTable_RepName) = 0) OR (LEN(FinalTable_RepName) > 60) THEN 0 ELSE 
                        CASE WHEN FinalTable_LocationId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
                    END 
                END 
            END 
         END AS BIT) AS StagingTable_IsValid 
FROM dbo.V_StagingConversion;
```

Next we create views that represent the future state and that are used for the respective `INSERT` queries:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.V_StagingPublicationFinal
AS
SELECT StagingTable_Id AS FinalTable_Id, StagingTable_ImportDateUtc AS FinalTable_ImportDateUtc, FinalTable_DateTime, FinalTable_BillNo, FinalTable_VendorId, FinalTable_RepName, FinalTable_LocationId 
FROM dbo.V_StagingValidation WHERE StagingTable_IsValid = 1;
```

and

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.V_StagingPublicationError
AS
SELECT StagingTable_Id AS ErrorTable_Id, StagingTable_ImportDateUtc AS ErrorTable_ImportDateUtc, StagingTable_DateTime AS ErrorTable_DateTime, StagingTable_BillNo AS ErrorTable_BillNo, StagingTable_VendorId AS ErrorTable_VendorId, StagingTable_RepFirstName AS ErrorTable_RepFirstName, StagingTable_RepLastName AS ErrorTable_RepLastName, StagingTable_LocationId AS ErrorTable_LocationId 
FROM dbo.V_StagingValidation WHERE StagingTable_IsValid = 0;
```

and a view that shows all processed records which we need for the `DELETE` query (if you do not like to delete the `StagingTable` records immediately after they have been inserted and processed, uncomment the according statement in the stored procedure).

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.V_StagingPublicationDone
AS
SELECT st.*, CAST(CASE WHEN ft.FinalTable_Id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT) AS StagingTable_IsValid FROM StagingTable st
LEFT OUTER JOIN FinalTable ft ON st.StagingTable_Id = ft.FinalTable_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ErrorTable et ON st.StagingTable_Id = et.ErrorTable_Id
WHERE (ft.FinalTable_Id IS NOT NULL) OR (et.ErrorTable_Id IS NOT NULL);
```

Then I decided to put the import logic into a stored procedure, that gives the flexibility to being able to manually execute it, e.g. if the trigger is disabled because one has to try something out or adjust something.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ImportStagingTable
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO dbo.FinalTable 
      SELECT FinalTable_Id, FinalTable_ImportDateUtc, FinalTable_DateTime, FinalTable_BillNo, FinalTable_VendorId, FinalTable_RepName, FinalTable_LocationId FROM V_StagingPublicationFinal p ORDER BY p.FinalTable_ImportDateUtc;
    INSERT INTO dbo.ErrorTable 
      SELECT ErrorTable_Id, ErrorTable_ImportDateUtc, ErrorTable_DateTime, ErrorTable_BillNo, ErrorTable_VendorId, ErrorTable_RepFirstName, ErrorTable_RepLastName, ErrorTable_LocationId FROM V_StagingPublicationError p ORDER BY p.ErrorTable_ImportDateUtc;
    DELETE st FROM dbo.V_StagingPublicationDone spd INNER JOIN dbo.StagingTable st ON spd.StagingTable_Id = st.StagingTable_Id;
END
```

Everybody should be able to execute this stored procedure:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.ImportStagingTable TO PUBLIC;
```

Finally we create the trigger. I added a COMMIT/BEGIN TRANSACTION to ensure the already written StagingTable records are not rolled back in case the after trigger fails:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.StagingTableAfterInsert ON dbo.StagingTable AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    EXECUTE dbo.ImportStagingTable;
END
```

and enable it (but it probably is already enabled):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.StagingTable ENABLE TRIGGER StagingTableAfterInsert
```

Now you can insert records into the `StagingTable` and they are automatically distributed into either `FinalTable` or `ErrorTable`.

Comment: Thanks @Christoph
I tried to add 'check constraint' in table but that did not worked for multiple conditions... then
I tried a similar approach as you suggested, instead of view I used tables and updated the same stage table using case statement. After that picked the good records and moved the errored records to another table for future reference.
Your solution helped

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it through an import table that has everything set to `NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL` like you suggested, then create a view over that table that determines whether the not yet imported records are valid or not, having an `IsValid` column and the other columns already converted into the target format, and an AFTER trigger on INSERT on the import table that inserts the records into the final- and the error tables respectively with something like

```
INSERT INTO finalTable (Date, billno, vendor, vendorId, repName, location)
  SELECT mv.Date, mv.billno, mv.vendor, mv.vendorId, mv.repName, mv.location FROM
    inserted i INNER JOIN MyImortView mv ON i.ID = mv.ID WHERE mv.IsValid = 1;

INSERT INTO errorTable (Date, billno, vendor, vendorId, repName, location)
  SELECT i.Date, i.billno, i.vendor, i.vendorId, i.repName, i.location FROM
    inserted i INNER JOIN MyImortView mv ON i.ID = mv.ID WHERE mv.IsValid = 0;
```

By the way, you should not use code constructs like this:

```
WHERE id > SELECT MAX(id) FROM finalTable
```

that's a time-bomb that may blow up anytime.

Comment: How to fill the 'IsValid' column in a view/table, should I check each column value in each record and update  'IsValid' column. My table has 52 columns, not getting how to check. Please give some details or example

Comment: @Vasanth: What SQLServer is it? Something recent or do you/I have to program the TryCast functions as well?

Comment: This is the one I get when running SELECT @@VERSION
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Jul 31 2020 08:26:29   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation